# How one can find the total number of digits in $n!$ raised to power $n$ where $n$ is in the millions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to find the total number of digits in $(n!)^n$.

For example:

```
n=5 
n!=120 
(n!)^n=24883200000
```

The total number of digits in the example is `11`.

Comment: First, please use $n!$ for the factorial ... $!n$ is the number of derangements of $n$ elements, which is something different.  Anyway, how about $\lceil log_{10} n! ^n \rceil$?

Comment: I would start with logs for n and then you can do the math more easily. You may even be able to use the sum of integers formula to find out how big the sum of powers of the factorial is.

Comment: $\log_{10} (n!)^n = n\log_{10}(n!)\approx n(n\log_{10} n - (\log_{10}e)n+O(\log_{10} n))$ as per Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of digits is Since $\left\lfloor\log_{10} n!^n+1\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\tfrac{n\ln n!}{\ln 10}+1\right\rfloor$, since $n!^n$ cannot be a power of $10$ (as you can prove by counting how often $2,\,5$ divide $n!$). If you'll settle for an approximate answer, use $\ln n!\approx\ln\sqrt{2\pi n}+n(\ln n-1)$; if you need an exact answer, have a computer compute $\ln n!$ as $\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k$.

Answer (score 0):

This simple Mathematica script generates results fairly quickly on my outdated MacBook, even for $n>10^6$

```
In[7]:= numDigits[n_] := Floor[n Sum[Log10[k], {k, 1, n}]] + 1

In[8]:= numDigits[5]

Out[8]= 11

In[9]:= numDigits[1000]

Out[9]= 2567605

In[10]:= numDigits[1000000]

Out[10]= 5565708917187

In[11]:= numDigits[10000000]

Out[11]= 656570590800575
```